# Ruby command download multiple folder from S3 use AWS CLI

Tags: ruby, aws-cli

I'm working on backup some accounts from my bucket with the prefix is `id`
When I exec once id is working correctly but when I used for multiple ids it will quit my ruby command. I was check, the error is when it run `exec command`. I was trying to research why it breaks but it takes more time. Anybody can help me why?

test.txt with 1 id:

```
1
```

test.txt with multiple ids:

```
1,2,3
```

My code:

```
file_names = ["test.txt"]
Dir.mkdir("logs") unless Dir.exist?("logs")
Dir.mkdir("data") unless Dir.exist?("data")

file_names.each do |file|
  out_file = File.new("logs/#{file}", "w")
  out_file.puts("Start read file #{file}")

  member_ids = File.read("#{file}").strip!.split(",")
  member_ids.each do |id|
    Dir.mkdir("data/#{id}") unless Dir.exist?("data/#{id}")
    command = "aws s3 sync s3://mybucket/#{id}/ data/#{id}/"

    exec command
    out_file.puts("#{id}")
  end

  out_file.puts("Finished read file #{file}")
  out_file.close
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This error by use `exec command`, change it to `system command` it will working :D